# Making sure private traffic doesn't go through work VPN using Shrew VPN?

Tags: vpn, tunnel

I'm using [ShrewSoft VPN](http://www.shrew.net/) client to access work VPN and I wanted to make sure that only work related traffic goes through the tunnel.

I know in Windows 7 there's an option «Use Default Gateway» or something like that but I can't find anything similar in Shrew's options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "route" command in your OS to force it to route the traffic for your office over the VPN tunnel, but everything else continues going through your standard internet connection.

```
 route add 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 "Shrew VPN Interface"
```

For more information, reference the [Microsoft page on it.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true)